# Followed Gazebo Model Plugin Tutorial however there is a Black Screen in Gazebo

Tags: gazebo-11, gazebo-plugin

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Followed Gazebo tutorial (http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=plugins_model&cat=write_plugin) however when typing all the commands Gazebo appears like this
[image: image description]

Here is the output from running the server command
[image: image description]

And here is the output from running the client command
[image: image description]

Can you guys please assist me with how to fix this problem?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/26420/followed-gazebo-model-plugin-tutorial-however-there-is-a-black-screen-in-gazebo/) by [James Chong](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/40868/james-chong/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 1 on 2021-01-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Had to change the sdf version from 1.4 to 1.5

---

Originally posted by [James Chong](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/40868/james-chong/) with karma: 1 on 2021-01-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0